# What is the missing number for level 9, question 78 in Think Different?

Tags: think-different

```
6  7  9  16  
4  3  2  4  
6  11 5  32  
18 10 13 ??
```

The numbers are in a square 4 by 4

How do I find the missing number as I can't see any link between the numbers. I have tried everything I can think of.

This is level 9, question 78 for Think Different on Android

Answer (score 3):

It appears that each column uses the same algebraic expression on the first 3 numbers, with the last row being a total.

- First Column: (6 x 4) - 6 = 18
- Second Column: (7 x 3) - 11 = 10
- Third Column: (9 x 2) - 5 = 13

So, for the fourth column, using the same pattern, you'd have:

(16 x 4) - 32 = ?

64 - 32 = **32**.